Не работает insert into в таблицу
У меня есть приложение клиент/серверное, типо мессенджера, и при запросе на создания нового диалога sql запрос выдает ошибку:
auto newDialogQuery = db->query("INSERT INTO Dialogs (channelid, lastMessage, lastMessageDate, companionfirst, companionsecond)"
              " VALUES (:channelid, :lastMessage, :lastMessageDate, :companionfirst, :companionsecond);");
newDialogQuery.bindValue(":channelid", idChannel);
newDialogQuery.bindValue(":lastMessage", QString("Start chatting!"));
newDialogQuery.bindValue(":lastMessageDate", time);
newDialogQuery.bindValue(":companionfirst", account->getUserInfo()- 
>getUserLogin());
newDialogQuery.bindValue(":companionsecond", companionLogin);
if (!db->execute(newDialogQuery)) {
    *request << replyes::internalServerError;
    return;
}

База данных:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
    login TEXT UNICAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    icon TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ChannelsIds (
    channelid TEXT UNICAL PRIMARY KEY,
    lastMessage TEXT,
    lastMessageDate datetime
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Dialogs (
    channelid TEXT UNICAL PRIMARY KEY,
    lastMessage TEXT,
    lastMessageDate datetime,
    companionfirst TEXT,
    companionsecond TEXT,

    FOREIGN KEY (companionfirst) REFERENCES Users(login) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (companionsecond) REFERENCES Users(login) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (channelid) REFERENCES ChannelsIds(channelid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    FOREIGN KEY (lastMessage) REFERENCES ChannelsIds(lastMessage) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    FOREIGN KEY (lastMessageDate) REFERENCES ChannelsIds(lastMessageDate) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Messages (
    messageid TEXT UNICAL PRIMARY KEY,
    channelid TEXT,
    owner TEXT,
    message TEXT,
    messageDate datetime,
    FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES Users(login) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (channelid) REFERENCES ChannelsIds(channelid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Members (
    channelid TEXT,
    memberid TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (channelid) REFERENCES ChannelsIds(channelid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (memberid) REFERENCES Users(login) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

lastError выдает следующее: "Parameter count mismatch"
Может неправильно как-то написал запрос, но аишка мне выдала такой же запрос который у меня был (первый запрос в этом вопросе копипаста ответа аишки). Нагуглил что эта ошибка выдается вообще почти всегда и при любых ошибках, так что не знаю куда копать. Думаю может быть что-то связано с foreign key (они кстати включены через pragma директиву первым запросом), в бд в таблице Users входные значения присутствуют (и входные значения я посмотрел через qDebug, они в порядке), а в ChannelsIds перед этим запросом создается запись, успешно. На всякий ее sql тоже приложу:
auto channelInsert = db->query("insert into ChannelsIds (channelid, lastMessage, lastMessageDate) VALUES (:channelid, :lastMessage, :lastMessageDate);");
    channelInsert.bindValue(":channelid", idChannel);
    channelInsert.bindValue(":lastMessage", QString("Start chatting!"));
    channelInsert.bindValue(":lastMessageDate", time);
    if (!db->execute(channelInsert)) {
        *request << replyes::internalServerError;
        return;
    }

Полностью код для маршрута пакета создания диалога:
    QSharedPointer<data::Account> account = managers::AccountsManager::instance()->getAccount(session()->token());
    if (!account) {
        *request << replyes::invalidToken;
        return;
    }
    QString companionLogin;
    *request >> companionLogin;
    if (companionLogin == account->getUserInfo()->getUserLogin()) {
        *request << replyes::channelWithSelfName;
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << "Companion login:" << companionLogin;

    auto db = Worker::databaseDevice();
    auto result = isDialogExists(account->getUserInfo()->getUserLogin(), companionLogin, db);
    if (!result.has_value()) {
        *request << replyes::internalServerError;
        return;
    }
    if (result.value() == true) {
        *request << replyes::channelAlreadyExists;
        return;
    }

    const QUuid idChannel = QUuid::createUuid();
    const QDateTime time = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    qDebug() << "Channel id:" << idChannel;
    qDebug() << "Time:" << time;
    {
        auto channelInsert = db->query("insert into ChannelsIds (channelid, lastMessage, lastMessageDate) VALUES (:channelid, :lastMessage, :lastMessageDate);");
        channelInsert.bindValue(":channelid", idChannel);
        channelInsert.bindValue(":lastMessage", QString("Start chatting!"));
        channelInsert.bindValue(":lastMessageDate", time);
        if (!db->execute(channelInsert)) {
            *request << replyes::internalServerError;
            return;
        }
    }

    {
        auto newDialogQuery = db->query("INSERT INTO Dialogs (channelid, lastMessage, lastMessageDate, companionfirst, companionsecond)"
              " VALUES (:channelid, :lastMessage, :lastMessageDate, :companionfirst, :companionsecond);");
        qDebug() << "User login:" <<account->getUserInfo()->getUserLogin();
        newDialogQuery.bindValue(":channelid", idChannel);
        newDialogQuery.bindValue(":lastMessage", QString("Start chatting!"));
        newDialogQuery.bindValue(":lastMessageDate", time);
        newDialogQuery.bindValue(":companionfirst", account->getUserInfo()->getUserLogin());
        newDialogQuery.bindValue(":companionsecond", companionLogin);
        if (!db->execute(newDialogQuery)) {
            *request << replyes::internalServerError;
            return;
        }
    }
    
    {
        auto membersQuery = db->query("INSERT INTO Members (memberid, channelid) VALUES (:memberid, :channelid)");
        membersQuery.bindValue(":memberid", account->getUserInfo()->getUserLogin());
        membersQuery.bindValue(":channelid", idChannel);
        if (!db->execute(membersQuery)) {
            *request << replyes::internalServerError;
            return;
        }
        membersQuery.bindValue(":memberid", companionLogin);
        if (!db->execute(membersQuery)) {
            *request << replyes::internalServerError;
            return;
        }
    }
    

    serialize::Dialog dialog;
    dialog.lastMessage = "Start chatting!";
    dialog.lastMessageDate = time;
    dialog.id = idChannel;
    std::optional<serialize::UserProfile> userProfile = loadUserProfile(companionLogin, db).value();
    if (!userProfile.has_value()) {
        *request << replyes::internalServerError;
        return;
    }
    dialog.companion = std::move(userProfile.value());
    *request << dialog << replyes::succesfull;

Логи от сервера при получении пакета
[18:01:47.962 0x25185f0 D] quty::server::handlers::ChannelsHandler::createDialog:168 - Companion login: "123123"
[18:01:47.963 0x25185f0 D] quty::server::handlers::ChannelsHandler::createDialog:183 - Channel id: QUuid("{6013f70b-27ab-41c8-be48-c6c82c161e7d}")
[18:01:47.963 0x25185f0 D] quty::server::handlers::ChannelsHandler::createDialog:184 - Time: QDateTime(2024-11-28 18:01:47.963 GMT+3 Qt::LocalTime)
[18:01:47.966 0x25185f0 D] quty::server::handlers::ChannelsHandler::createDialog:199 - User login: "1"
[18:01:47.966 0x25185f0 C] quty::server::database::DatabaseDevice::execute:43 - SQL error: "Parameter count mismatch"
[18:01:47.966 0x25185f0 C] quty::server::database::DatabaseDevice::execute:44 - SQL query: "INSERT INTO Dialogs (channelid, lastMessage, lastMessageDate, companionfirst, companionsecond) VALUES (:channelid, :lastMessage, :lastMessageDate, :companionfirst, :companionsecond);"

Таблица Users:

Таблица ChannelsIds:

UPD:
Изменил sql на создание таблиц с тестовыми insert-ами, теперь ошибка следующая: "createTables.sql" SQL statement error detail: "foreign key mismatch - \"Dialogs\" referencing \"ChannelsIds\" Unable to execute statement"
Сам sql:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
    login TEXT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    icon TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ChannelsIds (
    channelid TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    lastMessage TEXT,
    lastMessageDate TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(channelid, lastMessage, lastMessageDate)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Dialogs (
    channelid TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    lastMessage TEXT,
    lastMessageDate TEXT,
    companionfirst TEXT,
    companionsecond TEXT,

    PRIMARY KEY(channelid),
    FOREIGN KEY(channelid) REFERENCES ChannelsIds(channelid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(companionfirst) REFERENCES Users(login) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(companionsecond) REFERENCES Users(login) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(lastMessage) REFERENCES ChannelsIds(lastMessage) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(lastMessageDate) REFERENCES ChannelsIds(lastMessageDate) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Messages (
    messageid TEXT UNIQUE,
    channelid TEXT,
    owner TEXT,
    message TEXT,
    messageDate TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(messageid),
    FOREIGN KEY(channelid) REFERENCES ChannelsIds(channelid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(owner) REFERENCES Users(login) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Members (
    channelid TEXT,
    memberid TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(channelid) REFERENCES ChannelsIds(channelid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(memberid) REFERENCES Users(login) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO Users(login, username, password, icon) VALUES('1', '1', '123', '123');
INSERT INTO Users(login, username, password, icon) VALUES('123', '123', '123', '123');

INSERT INTO ChannelsIds(channelid, lastMessage, lastMessageDate) VALUES('112233', '1', '123');
INSERT INTO Dialogs(channelid, lastMessage, lastMessageDate, companionfirst, companionsecond) VALUES('112233', '1', '123', '1', '123');


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?. и заголовок исправьте на более адекватный.

Да вроде число параметров везде правильное. Нужно больше инфы какой-то.

@CrazyElf добавил больше деталей, логи и значения в таблице, полный код маршрута пакета

Попробуйте этот же запрос с теми же параметрами сделать "вручную" к БД. Сдаётся мне, что либо у вас primary key уже есть такой, либо проверки на FK не проходят.

в строке "INSERT INTO Dialogs у вас идет перевод строки, а далее еще одна строка и нет объеденения строк... Похоже просто "вторая" часть не участвует в вызове. Ошибка то у вас именно на этой вставке происходит, если верить логу(там User login: "1" стоит перед ошибкой)

У вас ошибки в определении таблиц. Что такое UNICAL? Имелся в виду UNIQUE? / В sqlite нет типа datetime. Он будет сконвертирован в numeric.

@AlexanderPetrov Ну, я надеялся, что автор хотя бы проверил, создана ли таблица вообще...

Покажите таблицу Dialogs @SwaD Нет у него там перевода строки. Строковые литералы склеиваются препроцессором без добавления символов.

@AlexanderPetrov да, давно не работал с sql, потому такая опечатка. Я сейчас изменил UNICAL на UNIQUE, но не работает все также (datetime тоже заменил, на TEXT, теперь qdatetime в бд записывается в виде строки и считыватся тоже)

Вы случайно не с AndroidStudio работаете? Насколько я помню, в этом фреймворке обязательно должен быть столбец с именем _id. Причём, IDE ошибку при его отсутствии не выдаёт. Тут подробнее.

@leb нет, это десктопное приложение на данный момент, компилирую под windows

сейчас попробую через db browser пересоздать базы sql, чтобы не самому писать. И там же попробую вручную сделать запрос

@CrazyElf вчера делал запрос в db browser вручную, мне выдало следующее: foreign key mismath (ChannelsIds), нашел следующее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848608/sqlite-foreign-key-mismatch-error, сейчас буду еще гуглить и пытаться исправить ошибку

Решил проблему, удалив столбцы lastMessage и lastMessageDate в Dialogs, оказывается недостаточно, чтобы столбец был primary key, он еще должен быть unique, чтобы foreign key мог на него ссылаться. Теперь отдельным запросом подгружаю сообщение из ChannelsIds.
